# cx_freeze no based named 'Win32GUI' error when creating a EXE

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I want to convert a application into an executable file and have use cx_freeze for that purpose.
But i got this Error-Message:

```
......executable.py, line 86, in base
raise ConfigError(f"no base named {name!r}")
cx_Freeze.exception.ConfigError: no base named 'Win32GUI'
```

Versions: Win 10 Home (x64); Python 3.9.6; Cx_Freeze 6.8; PyQt - 5.15.4;

It's strange because some time ago this code worked without problem?!

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

try:
    from cx_Freeze.hooks import get_qt_plugins_paths
except ImportError:
    include_files = []
else:
    # Inclusion of extra plugins (new in cx_Freeze 6.8b2)
    # cx_Freeze imports automatically the following plugins depending of the
    # use of some modules:
    # imageformats - QtGui
    # platforms - QtGui
    # mediaservice - QtMultimedia
    # printsupport - QtPrintSupport
    #
    # So, "platforms" is used here for demonstration purposes.
    include_files = get_qt_plugins_paths("PyQt5", "platforms")
   

# base="Win32GUI" should be used only for Windows GUI app
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

build_exe_options = {
    "excludes": [""],
    "include_files": include_files,
}

bdist_mac_options = {
    "bundle_name": "Test",
}

bdist_dmg_options = {
    "volume_label": "TEST",
}

executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base, target_name="TESTS")]

setup(
    name="simple_PyQt5",
    version="0.3",
    description="Sample cx_Freeze PyQt5 script",
    options={
        "build_exe": build_exe_options,
        "bdist_mac": bdist_mac_options,
        "bdist_dmg": bdist_dmg_options,
    },
    executables=executables,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution.
Updated all requirements (pip´s) and then it worked. Dont know why this happend but ok